# GitLab "Failed to create repository via gitlab-shell" No Errors

Tags: gitlab

I recently installed GitLab on Debian 8 and everything works except for creating projects. When trying to create I receive "Failed to create repository via gitlab-shell"

production log:

```
Started POST "/projects" for (my ip) at 2015-08-18 19:45:18 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "project"=>{"path"=>"test", "namespace_id"=>"2", "import_url"=>"", "description"=>"test", "visibility_level"=>"0"}}
Completed 200 OK in 799ms (Views: 386.7ms | ActiveRecord: 33.7ms)
```

sidekiq log:

```
2015-08-18T23:36:24.305Z 884 TID-zos08 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59945040 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:24.305Z 884 TID-znnls INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59905360 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:24.306Z 884 TID-zn7pk INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59872600 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:24.316Z 884 TID-zmuhg INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59855100 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:24.317Z 884 TID-alxtw INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 17779800 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:24.317Z 884 TID-b72xc INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 17884580 initialize
2015-08-18T23:36:25.087Z 884 TID-anxek INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.3.0 with redis options {:url=>"unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
2015-08-18T23:36:26.637Z 884 TID-anxek INFO: Running in ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
2015-08-18T23:36:26.637Z 884 TID-anxek INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2015-08-18T23:36:26.637Z 884 TID-anxek INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org/pro
```

gitlab:check

```
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.6.4 ? ... OK (2.6.4)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Satellites access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /home/git/repositories/: OK
        /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 3.0.3
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.1.5)
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (2.5.0)
Active users: 3

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

I haven't found anything specific on this when I'm not experiencing errors and everything is running like it should. Any help on this is appreciated

Update: The only thing I am seeing is this after running

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

-

```
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Rouge::Lexers::Shell::KEYWORDS
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:20: warning: previous definition of KEYWORDS was here
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant Rouge::Lexers::Shell::BUILTINS
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rouge-1.9.1/lib/rouge/lexers/shell.rb:25: warning: previous definition of BUILTINS was here

System information
System:         Debian 8.1
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.5p273
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.10.6
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0
rake aborted!
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>#<Project id: nil, name: nil, path: "some-project", description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, creator_id: nil, issues_enabled: true, wall_enabled: false, merge_requests_enabled: true, wiki_enabled: true, namespace_id: nil, issues_tracker: "gitlab", issues_tracker_id: nil, snippets_enabled: true, last_activity_at: nil, import_url: nil, visibility_level: 0, archived: false, avatar: nil, import_status: "none", repository_size: 0.0, star_count: 0, import_type: nil, import_source: nil, commit_count: 0>, :namespace_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:namespace_id]
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39:in `generate'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:613:in `generate'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:643:in `generate'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:679:in `url_for'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:411:in `url_for'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:230:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
/home/git/gitlab/app/models/project.rb:319:in `web_url'
/home/git/gitlab/app/models/project.rb:574:in `http_url_to_repo'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/info.rake:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:env:info
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wiping and installing Debian 7, everything works fine now.